# how can I get/set a value from interface of a map?

Tags: go

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
person := map[string]int {
    "age": 20,
}
var p interface{} = person
v := reflect.ValueOf(p)
// I want to get/set the value of age here from v e.g. v["age"]
// how can I do that
```

Comment: You can look into type assertion in Go: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use `reflect`, you can do type assertion:

```
person := map[string]int{
    "age": 20,
}
var p interface{} = person
age := p.(map[string]int)["age"] // get
p.(map[string]int)["something"] = 10 //set
```

Edit: It seems that your question is about the situation where you don't know the map key/value type. In that case, you can loop through the map elements with:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(p)
itr := v.MapRange()
for itr.Next() {
    fmt.Println(itr.Key(), itr.Value())
}
```

Or if you need a specific element, use:

```
v.MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("age")) // returns 20
```

Also for setting a new value, you can:

```
v.SetMapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("somekey"), reflect.ValueOf(7))
```

Comment: yes that works. but say I am passing the interface into  a function how can I get the type of the interface to do the type assertion. I tried reflect.TypeOf(p), it gives me an error

Comment: @MrByte *"but say I am passing the interface into a function"* That just doesn't matter, the type-assertion code in the answer will still work, regardless of where the interface comes from. And if there are possibilities that that interface may not always hold the `map[string]int` type then you better use the "comma ok" idiom, which is a special form of assignment supported by type assertions, that way you can avoid panics.

Comment: @mkopriva type assertion needs a type to work. in the function I don't know the type of the interface in runtime. it could be map[string]int or map[string]string

Comment: @MrByte you can always use a type switch, if however you want to support any kind of map type, then sure, you're better of with reflection, however for some reason you seem to have omitted that important requirement from your question.

Comment: @mkopriva yep that's what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: @MrByte if you need to use reflection: https://play.golang.org/p/b3FQEvik6hL

Comment: @MrByte I have updated the answer due to your question.